# symfony2: trying to send/receive push notifications (GCM) from controller. The code works from a standalone PHP script to send/receive them

Tags: android, symfony, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have the code below to send GCM push notifications. It works ok. Now I have just added it to a symfony action, but when I request the action the push notification is never sent.

After the action request, on my localhost the loading spinner inside the tab turns around and around.., and on my remote host I get a 500 error, but I can not find any error in Apache logs or symfony logs.

I have the same problem using this bundle: https://github.com/richsage/RMSPushNotificationsBundle

Any help?

```
    $message = "the test message";
    $tickerText = "ticker text message";
    $contentTitle = "content title";
    $contentText = "content body";

    $registrationId = 'abcdef...';
    $apiKey = "1234...";

    $headers = array("Content-Type:" . "application/json", "Authorization:" . "key=" . $apiKey);

    $data = array(
        'data' => $messageData,
        'registration_ids' => $registrationIdsArray
    );

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send" );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0 );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data) );

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
```

Comment: `$registrationIdsArray` and `$messageData` do not exist. Is this a typo?

Comment: @dbrumann Yes, there was a typo. Now it works, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$messageData and $registrationIdsArray doesn't exists.
and check if the api key is the browser api key.

Comment: and please don't share the api key and registration id when you put the code online. There are chances, it can be misused. You can edit the post and remove the api code..